# How to Access Pandas dataframe columns when the number of columns are unknown before hand

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am new to python and data science altogether.  I am writing a program to read and analyze a csv with pandas. The problem is that the csv will be supplied by the user and it can have variable number of columns depending on the user.  I do  not have a prior knowledge of the column names.
I went about the problem by reading the csv using pandas and read the column names into a python list. However problem ensued when I attempted to access the dataframe column by supplying the indexed list as a column name. something like this:

```
#List of column names, coln
coln = df.columns
df.ix[:, df.coln[0]] # to access the first column of the dataframe.
```

But this did not work. Please help how do I do this? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting pandas column by location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941097/selecting-pandas-column-by-location)

Answer (score 2):

Better is use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 0]
```

output is same as:

```
coln = df.columns
print (df.ix[:, coln[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iloc`

```
df.iloc[:,0]
```

Btw, `df.coln` does not exist you created `coln` as separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using iloc and not the method I corrected below as the other answers show, but to fix your original error:

```
coln = df.columns
df.ix[:, coln[0]] # to access the first column of the dataframe.
```

You wrote df.coln[0] instead of coln[0]. coln is a list, there is no such thing as df.coln.