# How to choose specific columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 25 columns and an array([ 2,  4,  8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], dtype=int64). I want to choose some specific columns from the dataframe whose indices are given by the elements of the array and store them in a new dataframe(say df1). So for example,the new dataframe, will have the 2nd, 4th,....23rd column of the original data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to accomplish this. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [np.random.rand(5),np.random.rand(5), np.random.rand(5), np.random.rand(5)]
)

df.iloc[:,[1,3]]
```

Which outputs:

```
    1           3
0   0.883848    0.409460
1   0.537549    0.426643
2   0.825185    0.361043
3   0.039343    0.674435
```

You may see older answers suggesting `.ix` (such as the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941097/selecting-pandas-column-by-location) that I adapted this from) however, that has been deprecated.