# Dropping lots of columns from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame with 100+ columns, how would I go about dropping, say, the last 15 columns?

Is there a better way than typing: `df.drop([column1,column2,...,column15])`? I have to input the names of all of the columns here. Is there not a way I can sort of slice, like something like `[column1 : column15]`?

Comment: What kind of is this? How did you end up with 100+ columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting pandas column by location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941097/selecting-pandas-column-by-location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the indexes of the columns you want to drop you could use

```
df.drop(df.columns[15:30], axis=1)
```

As mentioned in the comment by @fillbranden I should have shown you how to delete the last 15 columns with:

```
df.drop(df.columns[-15:], axis=1)
```

Comment: You have an extra set of brackets: `df.drop(df.columns[15:30], axis=1)` is the correct syntax. Also, for the *last* 15 columns (as requested by OP) you can use `df.columns[-15:]`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I should have paid better attention

Comment: Thanks for fixing! Yours was the best answer, just needed a small fix.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the last 15 columns from a dataframe:

```
df = df.iloc[:, :-15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with the made up dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size= (100, 15)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'))
```

In this case I dropped the last 5 columns using:

```
df.drop(df.iloc[:,10:15], inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df)
```

[image]

As long as you can easily use your column index, this should work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the last X columns if you don't know the specific column indexes:

```
cols = list(range(-1, -10, -1)) # Drop last 10 columns

df.drop(df.columns[cols], axis = 1)
```