# How to print a row in Pandas dataframe by its numerical index after assigning names to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, row

In the following code I get a “KeyError: 0”.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

data = pd.read_csv(…) #file name and other parameters

data.columns=['UNIX_UTC_Time', 'Home_Team', …] #columns names

matches_number=len(data.index)

def check_data_quality():
    for x in range (matches_number):
        for y in range (11): #number of columns
            if y==1 or y==2: #these columns are strings
                continue     
            if math.isnan(data.at[x,y]):
                print('NaN in:',data.at[x,y],'row',data.iloc[x])

check_data_quality()
```

Using loc instead of iloc doesn't help either.

If I remove data.columns line, then everything works.

Please let me know how I can print (whole) rows with unintended NaNs here.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting pandas column by location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941097/selecting-pandas-column-by-location)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `data.at[x,y]` with [`data.iloc[x,y]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Comment: Constantstranger,

thank you,

your solution worked!

Comment: It's even better to use data.iat here - for single cells.